# May I transit in Singapore if I am blacklisted from entry?

Tags: air-travel, transit, tickets, singapore, connecting-flights

One year ago, I was refused entry into Singapore and they told me that if I want to enter in the future I will need to apply with a letter to Immigration. I would like to travel to Indonesia and I am going to buy my tickets. The cheapest tickets are all transiting in Singapore.

Could they refuse me transit through Singapore (on the way to Indonesia) and deport me to where I came from? Do they check passports on connecting flights?

Comment: Are the connecting flights on the same ticket or on separate tickets? If the latter, do you have cehecked luggage and are you able to do online check-in? If you are on separate tickets and have hold luggage you will have to go through immigration to pick up your bags and check them back in.

Answer (score 8):

With Singapore, unlike the US, passengers who transit don't go through customs and immigration, thereby you will be OK to transit, provided you do not leave the airport i.e. go through customs and immigration. The only time they check your passport during transit, is for ID verification alongside your boarding pass.

The safest option is to call your nearest [Singapore Embassy/Consulate](https://www.embassy-worldwide.com/country/singapore/), and explain your situation as yourself, or alternatively you could contact your airliner.

Furthermore it might be good to have a record on when and who you spoke with at which Singaporean Embassy, should you have any problems while transiting.

Comment: Its better to call the embassy yourself rather than asking OP to do it. We are a Q&A site after all, not a "call the embassy" site :)

Comment: @JonathanReez Agrreed, however there is limited information provided by the OP. I don't  the intricate details of their refusal, and Singapore's grounds on the OPs blacklisting. If the OP were to call they may provide more information to the embassy, and get a far more accurate response.

Comment: Is that in site documents?  I think it is extremely unwise for us or anyone to do research on such a high-stakes topic for someone else when they can do it themselves.  On the other hand, in this case, might calling the embassy result in Singapore actively looking for the guy to give him a hard time?

Comment: @WGroleau writing "call the embassy" is essentially a "link only" answer as you're relying on an external resource to answer something for you. There are obviously cases where you *do* have to talk to the consulate (e.g. to apply for a visa), but generic questions can be resolved by calling the consulate instead of asking OP to do so.

Comment: @WGroleau also remember that questions are supposed to help many other people in the future, not just OP. So having a basic outline is better than unhelpfully guiding others to the phone.

Comment: Perhaps.  I'm willing to do a web search for someone less skilled at it, but I am not willing to tolerate the typical phone mess that bureaucrats like to set up.

Comment: @JonathanReez in some cases, the best answer is to tell the asker how to find the answer rather than to provide the answer directly.  This is just such a case.  As to the comparison with link-only answers, the critical problem with those is that links break.  The same is exceedingly unlikely to be true of a country's entire foreign service.  If you think a better answer can be had by calling the embassy and posting the result here, then you are welcome to do that.

Comment: @phoog this isn't just about OP (in fact, we don't like questions that only really benefit one person). Its about hundreds of future visitors who are in the same predicament and would like to receive a real answer to their question. Telling them to pick up the phone is a disservice, unless we are confident that the answer may change quickly.

Comment: @JonathanReez the answer gives as much information as could be hoped for the general case, and the instruction that for the specific case you need to call the consulate.  Your dissatisfaction with it is baffling.  It's not that the answer can change quickly, but, as noted by others, that the answer may depend on specific circumstances that have not been disclosed.